# Translate property acting differently in Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I have a few elements that I would like to translate on hover. However, while `translate()` works perfectly in Firefox, it seems that in Chrome the icons simply disappear instead of translating on the y-axis like in Firefox. I have already tried `transform: translate()`, `transform: translateY()`, neither of which seems to be working. The picture on the left is a depiction of what happens in Chrome, and the picture on the right is what it is supposed to be happening on hover (Firefox). Both my browsers are on the latest versions: Chrome Version 115.0.5790.102, Firefox Version 115.0.2.

[image: Chrome, icon disappearing on hover][image: Firefox, image translating properly on hover]

HTML:

```html
<div class="spacer waves"></div>
<div class="container">
    <section class="background-text">
        <strong>Hello</strong>
        <div class="icons">
            <a href="">
                <i class="fab fa-github"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="">
                <i class="fab fa-amazon"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="mailto:">
                <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #050f17;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

.background-text { 
    font-family: 'Lilita One', serif;
    font-size: 5em;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
    user-select: none;
    white-space: nowrap;

    fill:transparent;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    
    background-image: url("/images/gradient.jpg");
    background-size: cover;  

    animation: bg-animation 10s cubic-bezier(0.3,0,0.7,1) infinite;
}

.icons {
    display: flex;
    gap: 25px;
    line-height: 0.6em;
}

.background-text i {
    font-size: 0.6em;
    transition: all 0.375s ease;

    &:hover, :focus {
        translate: 0 -0.25em;
    }
}

@keyframes bg-animation {
    0% {background-position: 0% 0%;}
    50% {background-position: 100% 100%;}
    100% {background-position: 0% 0%;}
}

.spacer {
    position: absolute;
    aspect-ratio: 900/300;
    width: 100%;
    height: 650px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.waves {
    background-image: url(/images/waves.svg)
}
```

Comment: What was wrong with your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76750657/283366)? Why did you delete it, you even had an upvote?

Comment: @Phil I deleted it because I accidentally included my personal email in the original post and since edit history is visible to anyone, I had to delete it in order to hide my email. Sorry about the confusion. Also, I'm not sure if everyone can see my deleted post in the link you included, but if it is visible to everyone would you mind removing it please? Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to flag it. See [How to handle a publicly posted API key (or password, or other sensitive information)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258066/283366)

Comment: @Phil Alright, I flagged it. Thanks for the help.